# How to make website Responsive in mobile View

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I need to setup website into mobile responsive format. While checking on F12 the below code is compatible for ipad groups. The below is my css code.
#Result: To build this css into a mobile/ ipad friendly one.#
here the Divs are generated dynamically by jquery. All I need like this image

[image]

but getting like this:

[image]

This is generated divs

[image]

**.SCSS File**

```
#Main{
 width: 960px;
  margin:0px auto;
 overflow:hidden;

       }.Table1 
    {
    background-color: paleturquoise;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 9em !important;
    width: 40%;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #333;
    top: .5%;
    font-size:20px !important;
    }
    .width50 {
        width:50% !important;
    }

@media screen and (min-width:480px) {
    #Main {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .Table1 {
        width: 40%;
    }
 .Table2row1 {
        width: auto;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is HTML ?

Comment: could you give demo code in stackblitz  to make stack community work on it